# how to execute simple mysql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 select * from Labels where Label like '".$label."%' AND Label NOT IN ('$labels')
```

**$labels** is a string for example 'one','two','three'

Comment: Is the question how to execute or how to get that query to function (it appears your current query would have all `in` values quoted as one string)? You shouldn't have variables in SQL. That opens you to injections, parameterize the query.

Answer (score 3):

You use like this

```
Label::where('Label','LIKE','%'.$label.'%')->whereNotIn('Label', [$labels])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use [DB](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries) facade here

```
$sql = 'select * from Labels where Label like '".$label."%' AND Label NOT IN ('$labels')';
DB::select($sql);
```